# Downloaded files are read only

Tags: linux, firefox, gentoo, locked-files

I'm using the latest Firefox version (112) on Gentoo, and each time I download a file (even if it's compressed and I extract it) it's read only. I can fix this by simply changing the permissions but it's tedious especially when I download a compressed file that has 15+ files.

Is there a way to fix/troubleshoot this issue?

The output of `umask` command is `022`.

```
stat test-file
 
  File: test-file
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 0,22    Inode: 5056908     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   errorfof)   Gid: ( 1000/   errorfof)
Access: 2023-04-16 17:45:00.924064414 -0500
Modify: 2023-04-16 17:45:00.924064414 -0500
Change: 2023-04-16 17:45:00.924064414 -0500
Birth: 2023-04-16 17:45:00.924064414 -0500
```

Comment: Check your _umask_.

Comment: Are you saying the _contents_ are marked read-only once extracted?  What happens depends on what _type_ and how it was created as well as the _umask_ setting.

Comment: These files are not created locally, they are downloaded from websites using Firefox. So far, all types of files have a lock icon on them (read only permissions).

Comment: But they are _created locally_, just like any other file. Where the contents that are then written to the file come from is irrelevant. Text from a text editor or downloaded data from a browser, or even files extracted from an archive, it’s all the same to the filesystem. (Some archivers preserve permissions though, so keep that in mind.) // Take a step back. Open a terminal, run `touch test-file`, then `stat test-file`. Provide the output in your question.

Comment: If you extract files **as root**, most unarchivers will default to attempting to restore the ownership and permissions the original file had when it was compressed... which might result in the file getting a different owner than yourself, or even UID/GID numbers that don't match any valid user on **your** system. If extracting files **as a non-root user**, the unarchiver will have no choice but to have the extracted file(s) owned by you.

Comment: @telcoM: If anyone out there is downloading files from the internet **as root**, then you can tell them to defrag their storage device by using the command `cat /dev/null > /`. 
Anyway, this issue is puzzling because some files I download are fine but other's are not. I have used many Linux distros and BSD flavors and never experienced this issue, the only difference this time around is I'm using Gentoo.

Comment: Which filesystem type is used for your home directory (or wherever you see files becoming read-only)? Is it a remote share (NFS or SMB), or some kind of non-Unix-style filesystem like FAT32 or NTFS? Any of those might be applying their own rules in a way that is not immediately obvious: NFSv4 in particular has some surprises for anyone that's used to NFSv3 or older.

Comment: I'm using `btrfs`.